# How can I test that the data in my PostgreSQL table have no duplicate rows using my key columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table with key columns of user and date:

```
user   date              action           
1   2019-05-06 09:30:00 sent_email  
2   2019-05-13 09:30:00 sent_chat_message   
1   2019-05-20 09:30:00 sent_email
```

My question is what kind of python or sql test I can run to make sure that there will be no duplicates in my data based off user and date?

Also how can I test that I actually need to include action into my key columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `unique` constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_user_date unique (user, date);
```

If you try to insert a row with the same user and date as an existing row, the `insert` will return an error -- and similarly if you try to update values to conflict with an existing row.

Comment: this is a read only table. can you provide a query that may help?